# NMR without static magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-spin, precession, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

NMR is usually conducted by first aligning nuclei to a strong, constant magnetic field, so that you can apply RF radiation with a magnetic component directly perpendicular to the constant field. However, it seems to be that Larmor precession could be induced by any kind of RF radiation, because there will (almost) always be a component that is perpendicular to the effective magnetic field generated by fine and hyperfine interactions. As a result, why is the constant magnetic field so important to NMR? And have there been studies done into inducing Larmor precession with radio waves alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frequency of Larmor precession is directly proportional to the magnitude of the static magnetic field applied. It is not the rf radiation that induces Larmor precession the static magnetic field lifts the degeneracy of the Zeeman sublevels, the rf radiation couples the Zeeman sublevels, causing spin flips to other Zeeman states.